# Python 3 XML Duplicate and rename element if another element is not found

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an IN.xml file to fix that gave me headache :)

The problem to solve is to look in an IN.xml file if at least one "Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur" exist in "Donnees_Releve" element.

If not, then copy an "Classe_Temporelle" element (that always exist) and rename it "Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur".

Example below with the IN.xml and the expected OUT.xml file

This is how looks the IN.xml file

```
<filename>
 <prm>
  <Donnees_Releve>
   <Classe_Temporelle>
    <data></data>
   </Classe_Temporelle>
   <Classe_Temporelle>
    <data></data>
   </Classe_Temporelle>
  </Donnees_Releve>
 <Donnees_Releve>
   <Classe_Temporelle>
    <data></data>
   </Classe_Temporelle>
   <Classe_Temporelle>
    <data></data>
   </Classe_Temporelle>
  </Donnees_Releve> 
 </prm>
<filename>
```

This is the expected OUT.xml file

Note : The elements "Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur" are added if not presents within the "Donnees_Releve" node, it is a copy of Classe_Temporelle node.

Each element can have 1-n subelement
Each Classe_Temporelle should have a corresponding Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur, (every Classe_Temporelle don't contain the same datas.)

```
<filename>
     <prm>
      <Donnees_Releve>
       <Classe_Temporelle>
        <data></data>
       </Classe_Temporelle>
       <Classe_Temporelle>
        <data></data>
       </Classe_Temporelle>
       <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
        <data></data>
       </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
       <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
        <data></data>
       </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
      </Donnees_Releve>
      <Donnees_Releve>
       <Classe_Temporelle>
        <data></data>
       </Classe_Temporelle>
       <Classe_Temporelle>
        <data></data>
       </Classe_Temporelle>
       <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
        <data></data>
       </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
       <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
        <data></data>
       </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
      </Donnees_Releve> 
     </prm>
    <filename>
```

The code I wrote

Work partially but it only fix the first element "Classe_Temporelle" of each Donnees_Releve. But it can have many subelement then it don't match the request

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


file = 'IN/IN.xml'

tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

#loop on each PRM
for prm in root.iter('PRM'):


    # Loop on each Donnees_Releve

    for classeDistributeur in prm.iter('Donnees_Releve'):

        Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur = classeDistributeur.find('Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur')

        if Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur is None:
            print("Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur not found")

            # copy element Classe_Temporelle in Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur

            Classe_Temporelle = classeDistributeur.find('Classe_Temporelle')

            dupe = copy.deepcopy(Classe_Temporelle) #copy node
            classeDistributeur.append(dupe) #insert the new node

            # Rename Node
            Classe_Temporelle.tag = "Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur"


        else :
            print("Ok nothing to do")


tree.write('OUT/out.xml')
```

Could you please help me ?

Comment: is operator checks `type` only, test with ` == `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you call *find*, which finds only
the **first** occurrence of an element with the given name.
You should use *findall* and a loop instead.

Another (optional) correction is to use shorter names.

So change your code e.g. to:

```
for dr in root.iter('Donnees_Releve'):
    if dr.find('Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur') is None:
        for ct in dr.findall('Classe_Temporelle'):
            wrk = copy.deepcopy(ct)
            wrk.tag = 'Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur'
            dr.append(wrk)
```

I'm afraid that the other solution will copy existing *Classe_Temporelle*
elements to *Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur* regardless of whether this
element exists (in this case no copy should be made).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files, and avoid any procedural XML mappings at the general purpose level here being Python. While Python's built-in module, `etree`, does not support XSLT, it's third-party module, [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) does support XSLT 1.0 and full XPath 1.0.

Alternatively, have Python call any external [XSLT 1.0 - 3.0 processor](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) like Saxon or Xalan or even use any other general purpose language to run the XSLT transformation (i.e., Java, Javascript, C#, C++, PHP, Perl, R, VB) as each carries their own XSLT libraries.

Extending your example to feature the top three [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) and [XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) StackOverflow gold badge users, XSLT can easily duplicate needed nodes using multiple template modes.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Donnees_Releve">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Classe_Temporelle" mode="t1"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Classe_Temporelle" mode="t2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Classe_Temporelle" mode="t1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="data" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Classe_Temporelle" mode="t2">
    <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="data" />
    </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<filename>
 <prm>
  <Donnees_Releve>
   <Classe_Temporelle>
    <data>Martijn Pietersr</data>
   </Classe_Temporelle>
   <Classe_Temporelle>
    <data>Alex Martelli</data>
   </Classe_Temporelle>
   <Classe_Temporelle>
    <data>unutbu</data>
   </Classe_Temporelle>
  </Donnees_Releve>
 <Donnees_Releve>
   <Classe_Temporelle>
    <data>Dimitre Novatchev</data>
   </Classe_Temporelle>
   <Classe_Temporelle>
    <data>Martin Honnen</data>
   </Classe_Temporelle>
   <Classe_Temporelle>
    <data>Michael Kay</data>
   </Classe_Temporelle>
  </Donnees_Releve> 
 </prm>
</filename>
```

**Python** *(no `for` loop or `if` logic)*

```
import lxml.etree as et

# INPUT XML AND XSL SOURCES
xml = et.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('Script.xsl')

# RUN TRANSFORMATION
transformer = et.XSLT(xsl)
new_xml = transformer(xml)

# PRINT TO CONSOLE
print(new_xml)

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(new_xml)
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<filename>
  <prm>
    <Donnees_Releve>
      <Classe_Temporelle>
        <data>Martijn Pietersr</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle>
      <Classe_Temporelle>
        <data>Alex Martelli</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle>
      <Classe_Temporelle>
        <data>unutbu</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle>
      <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
        <data>Martijn Pietersr</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
      <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
        <data>Alex Martelli</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
      <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
        <data>unutbu</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
    </Donnees_Releve>
    <Donnees_Releve>
      <Classe_Temporelle>
        <data>Dimitre Novatchev</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle>
      <Classe_Temporelle>
        <data>Martin Honnen</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle>
      <Classe_Temporelle>
        <data>Michael Kay</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle>
      <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
        <data>Dimitre Novatchev</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
      <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
        <data>Martin Honnen</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
      <Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
        <data>Michael Kay</data>
      </Classe_Temporelle_Distributeur>
    </Donnees_Releve>
  </prm>
</filename>
```

## <kbd>[Online Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVEW/1)</kbd>